# Raspicam has low fps for OpenCV

Tags: streaming-video, opencv, raspicam

So far, I've tried these tutorials: [1](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14) & [2](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=62364). I have also attempted to use this [code](http://linux-projects.org/downloads/examples/opencv_test.cpp) to test it out, and the fps rate is quite low. It's just 2 -3 fps, which is not as high as when I stream via vlc from this [tutorial](http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-stream-video-from-your-raspicam-to-your-nexus-7-tablet-using-vlc).

What I want to do is be tracking objects using OpenCV.